# worker.port.emit() doesn't work, or, at least, the message isn't delivered

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

My problem is: A content script attached to a tab doesn't receive the message "start", and then doesn't execute.

The code seems correct, I looked for some related StackOverflow questions but I didn't find a solution.
The code is this:
main.js:

```
panel.port.on("process", function() {
    tabs.open({
        url: "./tab.html",
        onOpen: function(tab) {
            worker = tab.attach({
                contentScriptFile: [ "./cs1.js", "./cs2.js", "./cs3.js" ],
                contentScriptOptions: { data : data }
            })
        }
    });
    worker.port.emit("start", "start");
    console.log("worker emitted start");
});
```

cs3.js:

```
self.port.on("start", function(start) {
// do stuff
```

The message "worker emitted start" appears so I assume that the `emit()` has been executed, but there is no message from *cs3.js* and using the debugger I notice that *cs3.js* is never executed, despite being loaded.

Comment: Your code appears incomplete.  Among other things: where is `worker` defined (i.e. a `var` or `let` statement).  Please see:[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you have provided, the problem is that you are not accounting for the asynchronous nature of the code you have written.

Here is the order of what is happening in your code:

1. You call `tabs.open()` which asynchronously begins the process of opening a tab. You assign a function to be called when the `open` event fires.
2. `"start"` is emitted on the worker port.
3. The new tab's `open` event fires and the content scripts are attached.
4. The worker in *cs3.js* is waiting to see a `"start"` emitted from the main process.

As you can see the `"start"` is emitted prior to the tab being open and, thus, prior to the worker in *cs3.js* being attached to the tab.

Something along the lines of the following should work:

*main.js*:

```
var worker;
panel.port.on("process", function() {
    tabs.open({
        url: "./tab.html",
        onOpen: function(tab) {
            worker = tab.attach({
                contentScriptFile: [ "./cs1.js", "./cs2.js", "./cs3.js" ],
                contentScriptOptions: { data : data }
            })
            worker.port.emit("start", "start");
            console.log("emitted start to worker");
        }
    });
});
```